# Matrix problem in C

Tags: c, matrix, permutation, combinatorics

In an mxn matrix having k objects, what are the number of ways that an object be placed in a matrix cell.(k<=n,m). By giving an example the more better illustrated, if the 1st object out of the "k" objects was placed at location (1,1),then the next object could not be placed on the 1st column or on the 1st row, and on for rest of the remaining objects.

The output of the problem will be like: (kth object, nth row, mth column) i.e., (3,3,4)
or informally,"How many ways can k objects be placed on (nxm) matrix cells.

I found out the working rule,say : 
[n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-(k-1))][m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-(k-1))] --> this will give me exactly the number of ways, k objects can be placed in the cell, with the applied constraints.

But i can't construct the "nested for-loop" condition:
  for(object)
     for(row)
        for(column)

I AM USING C !

need some help in constructing the code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/how-to-compute-rook-polynomials-for-nxm-matrices/2671#2671), just implement [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20423/how-to-compute-the-rook-polynomial-of-a-ferrers-board).

```
/* n,m,k are constants */
int rook() {
    int i, j, mem[m+1][k+1];
    for (i=0; i<=m; i++)
        mem[i][0] = 1;
    for (j=1; j<=k; j++)
        mem[0][j] = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=m; i++)
        for (j=1; j<=k; j++)
            mem[i][j] = mem[i-1][j] + (n-j+1)*mem[i-1][j-1];
    return mem[m][k];
}
```

As usual, you can optimize this to use O(k) space.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [Rook polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial)